# How to get the tags in sequential order from two search inputs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have two search inputs A and B. The search value of A and B is represented as tags below the search inputs. Currently i'm pushing the search value of each inputs in an array and display them as tags, but it is not in the sequential order. For eg: The inputs of A will be displayed first and then the inputs of B are displayed in the tags. How to order them in the order of their inputs. Link to the code https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-dream-gpy4x

```
import React from "react";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import { Input, Tag } from "antd";

const { Search } = Input;

class SearchInputs extends React.Component {
  state = {
    tagsA: [],
    tagsB: []
  };

  onCloseTagA = (e, i) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      tagsA: this.state.tagsA.filter((_, index) => index !== i)
    });
  };
  onCloseTagB = (e, i) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      tagsB: this.state.tagsB.filter((_, index) => index !== i)
    });
  };
  handleSearchA = value => {
    console.log("The value", value);
    const { tagsA } = this.state;
    tagsA.push(value);
    this.setState({ tagsA });
  };
  handleSearchB = value => {
    const { tagsB } = this.state;
    tagsB.push(value);
    this.setState({ tagsB });
  };
  render() {
    const { tagsA, tagsB } = this.state;
    return (
      <div
        style={{
          margin: "50px auto",
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "column"
        }}
        className="search-input-main"
      >
        <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
          <div style={{ margin: "50px" }} className="search-input-a">
            Input A
            <Search
              placeholder="input search text"
              onSearch={this.handleSearchA}
              style={{ width: 200 }}
            />
          </div>
          <div style={{ margin: "50px" }} className="search-input-b">
            Input B
            <Search
              placeholder="input search text"
              onSearch={this.handleSearchB}
              style={{ width: 200 }}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>Tags of A and B</div>
        <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
          {tagsA.map((tag, i) => (
            <Tag
              style={{ margin: "5px" }}
              key={i}
              closable
              onClose={e => this.onCloseTagA(e, i)}
              color="#f50"
            >
              {tag}
            </Tag>
          ))}
          {tagsB.map((tag, i) => (
            <Tag
              style={{ margin: "5px" }}
              key={i}
              closable
              onClose={e => this.onCloseTagB(e, i)}
              color="#f50"
            >
              {tag}
            </Tag>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SearchInputs;
```

Comment: `in the order of their inputs` - where is this information available?

Answer (score 0):

I would advice to change the data structure for tags. 
Briefly I see two possible solutions:

1. Push all tags in one array instead of two. The array may look like this

```
[
    { tag: 'react', input: 'a' },
    { tag: 'jQuery', input: 'b' },
    ...
]
```

This method will have tags already stored in order of their inputs and array may be filtered to have two arrays - one for each input.

2. Push tags with additional data to order them

```
tagsA = [
    { tag: 'react', dateTime: '2020-03-19T00:09:53.344Z' }
];
tagsB = [
    { tag: 'jQuery', dateTime: '2020-03-19T00:10:23.344Z' }
];
```

Then have tags array to display like this

```
get tags() {
    return [...this.state.tagsA, ...this.state.tagsB].sort((a, b) => {
        return new Date(a.dateTime) - new Date(b.dateTime);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure as the description was not well put, but I assume you want to see the tags below in an order and no the way they are put in search inputs A or B.
Here I would add one more state variable and put all details into it.

```
import React from "react";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import { Input, Tag } from "antd";

const { Search } = Input;

class SearchInputs extends React.Component {
  state = {
    tagsA: [],
    tagsB: [],
    allTags: []
  };

  onCloseTagA = (e, i) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      tagsA: this.state.tagsA.filter((_, index) => index !== i),
      allTags: this.state.allTags.filter((_, index) => index !== i)
    });
  };
  onCloseTagB = (e, i) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      tagsB: this.state.tagsB.filter((_, index) => index !== i),
      allTags: this.state.allTags.filter((_, index) => index !== i)
    });
  };
  handleSearchA = value => {
    console.log("The value", value);
    const { tagsA, allTags } = this.state;
    tagsA.push(value);
    allTags.push(value);
    this.setState({ tagsA, allTags });
  };
  handleSearchB = value => {
    const { tagsB, allTags } = this.state;
    tagsB.push(value);
    allTags.push(value);
    this.setState({ tagsB, allTags });
  };
  render() {
    const { allTags } = this.state;
    return (
      <div
        style={{
          margin: "50px auto",
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "column"
        }}
        className="search-input-main"
      >
        <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
          <div style={{ margin: "50px" }} className="search-input-a">
            Input A
            <Search
              placeholder="input search text"
              onSearch={this.handleSearchA}
              style={{ width: 200 }}
            />
          </div>
          <div style={{ margin: "50px" }} className="search-input-b">
            Input B
            <Search
              placeholder="input search text"
              onSearch={this.handleSearchB}
              style={{ width: 200 }}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>Tags of A and B</div>
        <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
          {allTags.map((tag, i) => (
            <Tag
              style={{ margin: "5px" }}
              key={i}
              closable
              onClose={e => this.onCloseTagB(e, i)}
              color="#f50"
            >
              {tag}
            </Tag>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SearchInputs;
```